# Tomcat Context and JDBC... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

So I have a context.xml file placed under my META-INF.  There is only one context.xml file.

**My Question:**
When I pull the entry out of InitialContext using `jdbc/myDataSource`, I'm getting the very common "Name jdbc is not bound in this Context" exception.  How can I set up my Context/Tomcat to successfully return my DataSourceFactory when someone tries to fetch it out of InitialContext using `jdbc/myDataSource`?

**Note:** I don't have control over how the DataSourceFactory is being fetched. 
Also, I verified that I can access the datasource via `java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource`.

The Context entry in context.xml the file looks like this:

```
<Context shallowOutput="true" path="/">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

      <Resource name="jdbc/myDataSource"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            username="OMITTED"
            password="OMITTED"
            url="OMITTED"
            maxActive="20"
            maxIdle="10"
            maxWait="-1"/>
</Context>
```

The entry in my web.xml is like this:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDataSource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try java:/jdbc/myDataSource

Comment: would java:/jdbc/myDataSource go in the `res-ref-name` or the Resource name, or both?

Comment: naming in web.xml and context.xml will be same, but while accessing we need to add java: to any of the jndi resource name. To access JNDI resource out of container, we will be using java:comp/env and setting other context properties

Comment: As stated in the question, I can't control how the resource is accessed... it will always be accessed using "jdbc/myDataSource".  So, I need to configure my Web.xml or Context.xml to get this to work.

Comment: You will be configuring all required Datasources in context.xml and application specific datasource in web.xml